# Below python code running fine at first, but 2nd time getting loop since i have used same directory, where i need to change to avoid infinite loop?

Tags: python-3.x

My code running first fist time correctly since new.txt was not there. but second time getting infinite loop.

```
for file in files:   # here getting loop
    try:
        for line in open(file):
            line=line.strip()  
            print(line)                    
            with open (os.path.join(path,new),"a") as file: # creating new file and strong the exist file data's
                file.write(line)
                file.write("\n")
                file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can understand what the problem. When you open a 'new.txt' file you iterate it's lines, but on each iteration you add new line to it, so the lines number becomes "infinite" and you get infinite loop.

Comment: import glob
import errno
import os

file_path = 'd:/python/*.txt'
path='d:/python'
new="new.txt"
files = glob.glob(file_path)

for file in files:
    try:
        for line in open(file):
            line=line.strip()  
            print(line)                    
            with open (os.path.join(path,new),"a") as file:
                file.write(line)
                file.write("\n")
    except IOError as x:
        raise

Comment: Hi, i am reading 4 txt files and storing this datas to new file new.txt in same directory. So it was working fine. But now i have 5 text files in that directory. so code is taking new.txt file and adding text to new.txt, then again code is taking that added new line and adding this line to new.txt. and now it is infinite loop..

Comment: Yes, you right, I edited my answer. Didn't see that you found answer yourself.